# More efficient method for grabbing all child units

Tags: c#, sql, database

I have a table in SQL that links to itself through parentID. I want to find the children and their children and so forth until I find all the child objects. I have a recursive function that does this but it seems very ineffective.

Is there a way to get sql to find all child objects? If so how?

Using: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio Express 9.00.2047.00

Comment: These queries are generally written by hand (or a query designer) with `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: I want to find the children and their children and so forth until I find all the child objects

Comment: For what database?  Please include version.

Comment: Thanks. Now if you do a "New Query" => "SELECT @@VERSION" it would return something along the lines: "Microsoft SQL Server XXXX". What XXXX is in your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at using [Sql Server 2005 CTEs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        ID INT,
        Val VARCHAR(10),
        ParentID INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 1, 'A', NULL
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 2, 'B', NULL
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 3, 'C', 1
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 4, 'D', 1
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 5, 'E', 4
INSERT INTO @Table SELECT 5, 'F', 2

;WITh Parents AS (
    SELECT  *,
            CAST(Val + '/'  AS VARCHAR(100))PathVal
    FROm    @Table
    WHERE   ParentID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  t.*,
            CAST(p.PathVal + t.Val + '/' AS VARCHAR(100))
    FROM    @Table t INNER JOIN 
            Parents p ON t.ParentID = p.ID
)
SELECT  *
FROM    Parents
```

Depending on the depth of the tree, you might want to take a look at

[MAXRECURSION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx) query hint

Comment: Thanks this helped alot. I now understand recursive SQL thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [CTEs](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927200924/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/071906-1.shtml#postadlink).
[Using Common Table Expressions, MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx).
You need at least SQL Server 2005.

Comment: I want to find the children and their children and so forth until I find all the child objects

Comment: As andras said, you can do this with a recursive query and CTEs.  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like the [Nested Set Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model).

The idea is to store an additional two integers (usually called "left" and "right") for each node, calculated according to a system you can read more about by following the link. Then queries for all descendants of an arbitrary node becomes trivial.

**Edit:** [Here](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database/2) is a more detailed description.

Comment: Oh, just realized that maybe you can't change the schema for your table. If so, then this answer is useless. But if you can, this is an interesting option.